# CSS Triangles with clickable texts

Tags: html, css

I do not have experience with CSS, and would like to know how do I place texts that are clickable within each of the triangles?

```css
#pentagontopleft {
  margin: 70px 0 5px 150px;
  position: relative;
  border-width: 0 164px 222px 164px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #37272e transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(144deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(144deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(144deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
}

#pentagontopright {
  margin: 70px 0 5px -180px;
  position: relative;
  border-width: 0 164px 222px 164px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #37272e transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(216deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(216deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(216deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
}

#pentagonbotright {
  margin: -85px 0 5px -80px;
  position: relative;
  border-width: 0 164px 222px 164px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #37272e transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(288deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(288deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(288deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
}

#pentagonbotleft {
  margin: -85px 0 5px 100px;
  position: relative;
  border-width: 0 164px 222px 164px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #37272e transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(72deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(72deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(72deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
}

#pentagonbotmid {
  margin: -150px 0 5px 225px;
  width: 0;
  border-width: 0 164px 222px 164px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #37272e transparent;
  display: inline-block;
}

canvas {
  margin-left: -50px;
}

.log {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  border-top: 180px solid black;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}

.log:hover {
  border-top-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

.log:hover .login {
  color: #000;
}

.login {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  left: -50%;
  top: -90px;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 180px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 30px 0;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="pentagontopleft" class="pentagon"></div>
<div id="pentagontopright" class="pentagon"></div><br>
<div id="pentagonbotleft" class="pentagon"></div>
<div id="pentagonbotright" class="pentagon"></div><br>
<div id="pentagonbotmid" class="pentagon"></div>
```

It is not necessary that the triangles are this size, but preferably not change the size of them (poiss will not know how to correct later).

I'm also trying to put each of these triangles in a different color and I can not.

Comment: for the color it's easy, just change border-color

Answer (score 0):

you mean like that; [codePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YrZeXR)

use a instead of div, user border-color for giving color

```
<style>#pentagonbotmid{border-bottom-color:#E1B225} #pentagontopleft{border-bottom-color:#F48024}#pentagontopright{border-bottom-color:#DC4E51}#pentagonbotright{border-bottom-color:#1DA1F2}#pentagonbotleft{border-bottom-color:#4267B2}</style>
```